# Abstract and TOC-start on odd page

Tags: table-of-contents, double-sided, abstract

I'm having a twosided document (compiled with pdflatex, pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16).
How can I make the abstract and TOC begin on odd pages? I don't know if this is even default, but for me it doesn't work. I want completely blank pages (pagestyle=empty) on the pages before.

Here an MWE:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
twoside,
openright,
12pt
]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\include{titlepage} %...

%here a blank page
\begin{abstract}
... 
\end{abstract}
%and here a blank page
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

I already made experiments with \newpage and \clearpage, but this doesn't  work properly (headers included) and is hackish.
The nextpage-package and \cleardoublepage-command have no effects.
The missing page before the TOC has to do with the

Comment: For me your examples compiles exactly as you requested it. I replaced your `\include{titlepage}` with `\title{test}\maketitle`however. Maybe you need to update your komascript package?

Comment: okay, I also had to extend it to get nearer to my real doc (wasn't/isn't a real MWE). the pagenumbering and setcounter commands made a difference, when I deleted them a blank page before the TOC appeared suddenly. but now it makes no difference when I re-add the commands!? blank page stays. I don't get it. Did it need a clean rebuild?
The blank page before abstract is still missing. with overleaf I couldn't reproduce it, there was a blank page. Can I update the package when it's the latest from the ubuntu-repo (comes with texlive-latex-recommended,  Version 2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\cleardoublepage` or better the KOMA-Script command `\cleardoubleoddpage` before each `\pagenumbering` command. Then there is no need to set the page counter explicitly.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
twoside,
open=right,
fontsize=12pt
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\title{Title}\author{Author}\maketitle

%\cleardoubleoddpage
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\cleardoubleoddpage% <- add this before each \pagenumbering command
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]